# PostgreSQL group by and count on specific condition

Tags: postgresql, join, select, group-by, count

I have the following tables (example)

**Analyze_Line**

| id | game_id | bet_result | game_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | WIN | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | LOSE | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | WIN | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | LOSE | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | LOSE | 0 |
| 6 | 6 | WIN | 0 |

**Game**

| id | league_id | home_team_id | away_team_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 3 | 4 |

**Required Data:**

| league_id | WIN | LOSE | GameCnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 2 |

The **Analyze_Line** table is joined with the **Game** table and simple can get **GameCnt** grouping by league_id, but I am not sure how to calculate **WIN** count and **LOSE** count in **bet_result**

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Kamil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70197965/2422776) - PostgreSQL introduced the filter clause in PostgreSQL 9.4, released about eight years ago (December 2014). At this point, I think it's safe enough to use in answers. IMHO, it's a tad more elegant than summing over a `case` expression, but it does have the drawback of being PostgreSQL specific syntax, and thus not portable:

```sql
SELECT   g.league_id,
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE a.bet_result = 'WIN') AS win,
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE a.bet_result = 'LOSE') AS lose,
         COUNT(*) AS gamecnt
FROM     game g
JOIN     analyze_line a ON g.id = a.game_id
GROUP BY g.league_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditionals in aggregate function to divide win and lose bet results per league.

```
select
  g.league_id,
  sum(case when a.bet_result = 'WIN' then 1 end) as win,
  sum(case when a.bet_result = 'LOSE' then 1 end) as lose,
  count(*) as gamecnt
from 
  game g
  inner join analyze_line a on
    g.id = a.game_id
group by 
  g.league_id
```

Since there is no mention of postgresql version, I can't recommend using `FILTER` clause (postgres specific), since it might not work for you.